# Which is better for health tea, water tea or milk tea?

Tags: caffeine, tea, milk, glucose

From which of the following is better for health : tea with milk or tea with milk and water in equal proportions and spices  or tea in water with spices, If someone can link to some authentic source supporting his point that .and if it is beneficial  how much consumption of tea cups(200 ml)  is okay for a day ?

Comment: Define *tea;* define *spices.*

Comment: A seed for spam.

Answer (score 1):

The only well studied effects of drinking tea are the Green Tea Catechins:

> I would highly recommend people pay attention to the bioavailability
>   issue and pay attention to [Quercetin](http://examine.com/supplements/quercetin/). Green tea seems Godly in vitro,
>   but it has high variability in people because not 100% of the
>   catechins get to the cell to exert effects. Any supplementation with
>   green tea catechins, in my opinion, should have thought given to
>   increasing bioavailability through [Quercetin](http://examine.com/supplements/quercetin/), [Fish Oil](http://examine.com/supplements/fish-oil/), or consuming
>   green tea with a meal that has these two.
>
> The combination of all four catechins seems to be better than just
>   isolated EGCG, although pairing an EGCG capsule with a cup of green
>   tea would be even better.
>
> —   Kurtis Frank
>
> http://examine.com/supplements/Green+Tea+Catechins/

The above site references many studies but the overall conclusion is green tea is really good for you, drink it:

> It has been implicated in benefiting almost every organ system in the
>   body. It is cardioprotective, neuroprotective, anti-obesity,
>   anti-carcinogenic, anti-diabetic, anti-artherogenic, liver protective
>   and beneficial for blood vessel health. These beneficial effects are
>   seen in doses present both in green tea itself (as a drink) as well as
>   from a supplemental form.